# How to filter column values from a file and write in a new file in python

Tags: python, numpy

I have a .txt file with columns

```
#x y z
1 4 6
2 5 6 
3 6 8
4 8 8
5 7 8
6 7 8
```

The first column is sorted in an ascending order. I want to filter the first column x for values between 2 and 6 and then create a new file with corresponding y and z columns

So the output file looks like:

```
# x y z
  3 6 8
  4 8 8
  5 7 8
```

This simple lines filters the x columns, but how do I get the corresponding other columns to write to a new file?

```
x=x[np.where(x>2)]
print x
x=x[np.where(x<6)]
print x
```

Your help is very apppreciated

Comment: `x=x[np.where(2<x<6)]`? Is that the question?

Comment: I also need to know the indices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `np.where` to get the indices for entries that satisfy the condition and then save only those rows to file,

```
import numpy as np

data_in = np.loadtxt('xyz.txt', dtype = int)

idx = np.where(np.logical_and(data_in[:,0]>2, data_in[:,0]<6))[0]

np.savetxt('xyz_filtered.txt', data_in[idx,:], fmt = '%d')
```

This assumed that you don't have any header in your input file and that you want all your data as integers, but any necessary changes would not influence the program much.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is exactly what you want but filtering the array that you get from the input file is a viable option. Here's the code:

```
filename = 'table.txt'

with open(filename, mode='rt') as file:
    table = [[int(n) for n in line.split()] for line in file]

predicate = lambda l: 2 < l[0] < 6
table = filter(predicate, table)

with open('output.txt', mode='wt') as file:
    for row in table:
        line = ' '.join(map(str, row))
        file.write(line + '\n')
```